# Bitwise Operations Help/Suggestions

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, cpu-architecture

Alright, I'm not looking for answers or anything like that. So on recent exams, when I've been asked to perform some relatively simple bitwise operations, I just can't seem to get the job done. Given 30 minutes to an hour, I could flush it out, but with 10 minutes or less, I just get stuck.

For example, i was recently asked to  write a small function, if x > y,return 1, else 0. 
 I couldnt for the life of me provide an answer. After the exam, I went home and wrote out the answer, but it took me half an hour.

Im doing my best to get faster at this because I know I'm going to get these kind of questions again on the final.

What are some rules, axioms, or anything that I can utilize to help me get going on these kind of problems. When you see a problem like this, what reasoning helps you form an answer.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what the question was.

Comment: Well, knowing some boolean algebra kinda helps.

Comment: Post-edit: you need to do a lot more study and write some software.  We can't help at the level you seem to have reached.

Comment: One of the best references that will help you along is [**The Art of Assembly**](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/artofasm.html). You will want to look at **Chapters 2, 6 & 9** in particular and pay attention to the `cmp`, `test`, and `conditional jmp` instruction descriptions. There are other references, but this is a good generally available reference. Just like math, repetition (using it enough for it to sink in) is the key to getting faster and more confident.

Comment: `return (x > y);`? Or even `if (x > y) return 1; else return 0;`? Not sure what that has to do with bit-manipulation or what-not, though...

Comment: @twalberg It's a puzzle problem on an exam. The obvious answers are disallowed by the rules in the question.

Comment: @user3386109 And you gained that particular insight from which statements in the question? I guess perhaps I'm not completely in-the-loop on this one... Also not sure where the assembly suggestions are coming from, as the question is tagged C...

Comment: @twalberg yes, that insight comes from the first paragraph, and any number of similar "I want to do something trivial, but I'm not allowed to do it in any sensible fashion" questions.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need the following general knowledge

- understanding of the C operators
- 2's complement arithmetic
- boolean algebra

---

A trick that may come in handy is *n-bit folding*. For example, let's say I'm given a 32-bit value as the argument to my function, and I need to return 1 if any of the bits is 1, or 0 otherwise.  (Further assume that the rules of the question don't allow me to do this in any sensible fashion.) Then my function would look like this

```
int hasBitsSet(uint32_t value)
{
    value |= value >> 16;
    value |= value >>  8;
    value |= value >>  4;
    value |= value >>  2;
    value |= value >>  1;

    return value & 1;
}
```

The first five lines of the function "fold" the 32-bit value, so that if any bit is a 1, then the LSB of the result will be a 1. The last line of the function returns the LSB.  Using brute force boolean algebra, the equivalent function is

```
int hasBitsSet(uint32_t value)
{
    uint32_t bit31 = (value >> 31) & 1;
    uint32_t bit30 = (value >> 30) & 1;
    ...
    uint32_t bit0  = value & 1;

    return bit31 | bit30 | ... | bit0;
}
```

The point is that *folding* is sometimes useful in reducing the amount of code that you have to write, but anything that you can do with *folding* can also be done with brute-force boolean algebra. So if you're not sure whether *folding* will work, then just do algebra.

---

The final thing I'll mention is that comparisons are often implemented by subtraction. In other words, to determine whether `x > y`, first compute `x - y`, and then check whether the result is positive.  In 2's complement arithmetic, a number is positive if the MSB is 0 and at least one of the other bits is a 1. So you could extract the MSB, fold the other 31 bits, and then use boolean algebra to generate the final result.

That last bit of knowledge (comparison equivalence to subtraction) is problem-specific and is especially troublesome since every question will have some arcane tidbit of knowledge that makes the question easier. All you can do about that is pay attention in class and hope that those little gems stick in your mind when they're mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. Very helpful and more than I was hoping for.

Comment: @i_know_nothing If this answers your question, you can click on the check mark below upvote/downvote arrows to accept the answer.

Comment: _"to return 1 if any of the bits is 1, or 0 otherwise."_  : `return (value != 0);` will do that.

Comment: @Clifford True, but bit-folding is typically needed for homework problems or puzzles that restrict which operators can be used. And comparison operators are typically not on the list of allowed operators.

Comment: @user3386109 : Fair enough.