# Checking bits of ints to see if they share binary with the power of 2 (bitwise only)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to recreate this function:

```
int test(int x) {
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 32; i+=2)
   if ((x & (1<<i)) == 0)
      return 0;
   return 1; 
}
```

But only using these bit-wise operators:  !, ~, &, ^, |, +, <<, and >>
(Meaning no loops or if statements either)

I am so confused with this question I have been staring at it for like a hour and am still not sure where to start.

I understand that basically it is taking x comparing it with 2^i where i is 0-31 and then returning 0 if x and 2^i do not share any of the same bits and returning 1 otherwise.

But I feel like there is a more simple, non-bit focused explanation that summarizes this better and if someone could even just give me that it would be a huge help.

Comment: Name of the function is not doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: _"it is taking x comparing it with 2^i where i is 0-31"_  - I beg to differ. The iteration is only over even bit numbers 0,2,4...30.  and it aborts early when it encounters the first even numbered zero bit.   It is entirely unclear what the code is intended to do or even what the description in the title could mean.  We need an unambiguous specification of the requirement.  This code does not do what you think it does, and we don't know what it is supposed to do, or why you have imposed the constraints (homework I guess).

Comment: The code returns 1 if all even numbered bits are 1, and zero otherwise.  That does not bear any similarity to your question or explanation of the code.  Have you posted the wrong code for this question?

Comment: The answer is yet another variation on the [bit folding technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640271/3386109). I'll leave it to you to adapt the technique to your particular case.

Comment: The solution is trivial but relies on your correct interpretation of what the current code does, which is currently not correct.  Understanding the code may lead you to an answer.

Comment: @user3386109 : The answer you linked is nonsense.  The `hasBitsSet()` function in that answer can be replaced with `return (value != 0);`.  The solution to this is almost as simple.  The code in this question does not do what the OP thinks it does.  It is currently unclear therefore what the question is - implement the code, or implement the description (which cannot be done in any case because it is nonsense).

Comment: @Clifford For i being 0 - 31, and being incremented by 2, that iteration would be 1,4,16 ... so there's one *non-even* bit number and not all even bits are checked. I'm not trying to make anything out of it, just pointing out a detail.

Comment: @gst : Read the _code_ being described - not the description of what the OP erroneously _thinks_ the code does! `for (i = 0; i < 32; i+=2)`

Comment: @Clifford In the loop `(x & (1<<i)) == 0` when `i == 0`, `1 << i == 1`. And in the next iteration, when `i == 2`, `1 << i == 4`, *etc.*

Comment: @gst : I do not see your point. The sequence of `i` is 0, 2, 4..., `1<<i`, selects bit0, bit2, bit4... i.e. _even numbered bits_, (not even numbered _values_).

Comment: @Clifford Pardon, I misinterpreted what you're saying!

Comment: Are you sure you cannot also use `( )` and `==` operators?  Of the operators listed only `&` is required.

Comment: @user3386109   I take that back - since `( )` and `==` are not in the allowed list, bit-folding may indeed be the answer.  Seems a little complex an assignment given the OP apparent level of understanding.  `return (x & 0x55555555) == 0x55555555 ;` is the obvious solution, but uses disallowed operators.

Comment: Note that `!` and `+` in your list are _not_ a bit-wise operators.  Perhaps you or your teacher intended `~` rather than `!`?  It only further serves to make this question entirely unclear.

Comment: If you want to replicate the code with coding constraints, simply ask about that. 
 If you want someone to explain what the code does, ask about that..  Here you have instead asked about implementing what you _think_ that code does, which is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what the question is here but from:

> But I feel like there is a more simple, non-bit focused explanation
>   that summarizes this better and if someone could even just give me
>   that it would be a huge help.

It seems you are simply asking for a description of what the code does.  That being the case, your stated understanding is entirely incorrect.  The behaviour of the code is simply:

- Return 1 if all *even* numbered bits are 1, and zero otherwise.

Comment: @ clifford wouldn't, the current implementation always return a `0`.Unless the user encloses `return 1` within the for loop.

Comment: @LilyAB if all even bits are 1, the loop completes and returns 1

Answer (score 2):

As has already been stated, the minimal solution would be

```
return (x & 0x55555555) == 0x55555555 ;
```

However, this uses '==', which is not in the list of allowed operators. Comparisons of integers is more or less equivalent to seeing if the difference between the numbers is zero or not, but '-' is also not in the list of allowed operators, but '+' is. Setting the first bit in a signed integer is equivalent to making it negative and subtracting 1. Therefore, the function can be written as:

```
return !(((x & 0x55555555) | 0x80000000) + 0x55555556);
```

This assumes the input is not negative, and it also seems to fail for very large input, but works for numbers in the range 0 to 1431655764 in my tests. 
Also, this assumes 32-bit integers.

Edit: The XOR operator is obviously a much better substitute for '==':

```
return !((x & 0x55555555) ^ 0x55555555);
```

Works for negative numbers too!

Comment: Good work, though I was trying to avoid doing his homework, and I dislike these "too clever" puzzles that do little to make anyone a more proficient programmer.  Eradicating the loop is beneficial and shows understanding - everything else is obfuscation.  Strictly parentheses `(...)` are an operator in C, and not on the list.  But the author of the question may not have appreciated that.  Also the question appears only to be asking for a description of what the code does rather then an actual solution - there is a lot of redundant and erroneous information in the question IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I think we are in the same, or similar classes :). However if that is true make sure to remember that any numbers you use would need to be below 0xff. So 0x55555555 would need to be (0x55 << 24) | (0x55 << 16) | (0x55 << 8) | 0x55) (although there is probably a better way to do this).

I have the same question, but I also have the variant:

```
int testdl4(int x) {
   int i;
   for (i = 1; i < 32; i+=2)
       if ((x & (1<<i)) == 0)
          return 0;
   return 1; 
}
```

How would starting with a 1 instead of a 0 for i change the 3rd answer given by @Johnny Johansson? (Same bit-wise limitations)

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be testing negative numbers to see if they & with the powers of every other 2

```
def testit(x):
   print ( bin(x), test(x))

def test(x):
   for i in range (0, 32, 2):
      if ((x & (1<<i))) == 0:
           print(x, bin(x), bin(1<<i))
           print("{} & {} ({}) is 0".format(x, 1<<i))
           return 0
   print(x, bin(x), ((x & (1<<i))), bin(((x & (1<<i)))))
   return 1
```

```
In [494]: testit(-2)                                                                                                                           
-2 -0b10 0b1
-2 & 1 is 0
-0b10 0

In [495]: testit(-3)                                                                                                                           
-3 -0b11 1073741824 0b1000000000000000000000000000000
-0b11 1

In [496]: testit(-4)                                                                                                                           
-4 -0b100 0b1
-4 & 1 is 0
-0b100 0

In [497]: testit(-5)                                                                                                                           
-5 -0b101 0b100
-5 & 4 is 0
-0b101 0

In [498]: testit(-6)                                                                                                                           
-6 -0b110 0b1
-6 & 1 is 0
-0b110 0

In [499]: testit(-7)                                                                                                                           
-7 -0b111 0b100
-7 & 4 is 0
-0b111 0

In [500]: testit(-8)                                                                                                                           
-8 -0b1000 0b1
-8 & 1 is 0
-0b1000 0

In [501]: testit(-9)                                                                                                                           
-9 -0b1001 1073741824 0b1000000000000000000000000000000
-0b1001 1

In [508]: testit(-17)                                                                                                                          
-17 -0b10001 0b10000
-17 & 16 is 0
-0b10001 0

In [515]: testit(-203)                                                                                                                         
-203 -0b11001011 0b1000000
-203 & 64 is 0
-0b11001011 0
```

The above output shows that every other powers of two number that & with your negative number will be 0, if not it quits checking at powers of two of 1073741824. Does this help?

Comment: No it really doesn't do that.  Have you read the existing answers?  And still wrong language.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to see if numbers share the same bitlength's you can use this:

```
def log2_floor(x): 
  res=-1 
  while x: 
     res+=1 
     x = x>>1 
  return res 

def compare_bitlength(hm, hm2):
   hmone = log2_floor(hm)
   hmtwo = log2_floor(hm2)
   if hmone == hmtwo:
      print (f'{hm} and {hm2} share the same bitlength of {hmone}')
   else:
      print (f'{hm} has bitlength {hmone} and {hm2} has bitlength {hmtwo} and are not the same bitlength')


In [351]: compare_bitlength(15,14)                                                                       
15 and 14 share the same bitlength of 3
```