# Using given bitwise operators to reproduce function

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a question very similar to the one here [Checking bits of ints to see if they share binary with the power of 2 (bitwise only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58655811/checking-bits-of-ints-to-see-if-they-share-binary-with-the-power-of-2-bitwise-o/58667739#58667739) , however the question was frankly poorly worded (so i'm not sure how similar they are) and the answer was not explained much.

Trying to replicate this function:

```
    int testdl4(int x) {
       int i;
       for (i = 1; i < 32; i+=2)
           if ((x & (1<<i)) == 0)
              return 0;
       return 1; 
    }
```

Using only these bit-wise operators: !, ~, &, ^, |, +, <<, and >> (Meaning no loops or if statements either).

The answer on aforementioned link (Same question I think, but with loop starting at 0) was:

return !((x & 0x55555555) ^ 0x55555555);

And I believe the mask needs to be changed to get it to work, but I am not sure 2 what.

Could someone please solve & explain reasoning?

Comment: the code has undefined behaviour as per C standard in any implementation that does not have at least 33-bit wide ints...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by writing what your code actually does, in English:

```
If any odd numbered bit (from 1 to 31) is clear return 0; otherwise return 1.
```

Now "`any odd numbered bit (from 1 to 31)`" is the binary value 10101010101010101010101010101010b, which is `0xAAAAAAAAUL`. Note that this value is not possible for signed 32-bit integers, so we want to use unsigned integers that are at least 32 bits.

If any bit is clear, then `x & 0xAAAAAAAAUL` won't be equal to `0xAAAAAAAAUL`.

That gives:

```
int testdl4(unsigned long x) {
    if( (x & 0xAAAAAAAAUL) != 0xAAAAAAAAUL) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Note that this does include an `if` to get the same behavior as your original code (e.g. returning `1` and not returning a messed up non-zero value).

However, the logical NOT `!` will force a non-zero value to become zero and a zero value to become 1; so you can do:

```
int testdl4(unsigned long x) {
    return !((x & 0xAAAAAAAAUL) ^ 0xAAAAAAAAUL);
}
```